# which excel formula should I use

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

There are two timing which is the OperatingTime and DownTime. So if the DownTime is less than the TurnAroundTime and DownTime is outside the range of OperatingTime then the PC is fine. If the DownTime is more than the TurnAroundTime but it is outside the OperatingTime then also the PC is fine. But if the DownTime is within the range of OperatingTime and the DownTime is greater than TurnAroundTime then the PC is bad.

As you can see in the image, the total DownTime was greater than 2 hours(TurnAroundTime) but it is still fine cause the DownTime was outside the range of Operating Range. How do I do this with a formula? What would be the condition for this?

P.S- The DownTime can extend till the next day too and it would be counted

[image: Excel]

Comment: If I read your question correctly, the time period for down time can extend into the next day. In your screenshot, 1:37 hrs are actually in the operating time of the next day, is that correct? And when we go into this, what about weekends?? Are there any operating hours on weekend days? Are there any days without operating hours? This will be a very complex formula.

Comment: yeah the downtime can go till the next day so it will come within the operating range too of the next time.. no weekends. consider everyday as normal

Comment: Are the operating hours always the same, i.e. 8 am to 6 pm?

Comment: @MLnewb,, could you please [Edit] your post & reload the Screen Shot ,, should open on click!

Answer (score 0):

First, I assume that you don't work with days in week (like weekends somebody mentioned yet) and the computer is up sooner than after 24 hours. Try this formula, it will work:

```
=if(A2>E2, if(B2<D2, 0, B2-D2), if(B2<D2, A2-D2, A2-B2))
```

If computer can be up after 24 hours, you should start to work with datetime values, not only with time values.

Best regards, Lukas

Comment: You're avoiding the main problem.